# Why is my CSS/JS not working on Github pages?

Tags: javascript, html, css, github, github-pages

I have looked through many similar questions and tried several different solutions, but I do not understand what I am doing wrong. Examining the console did not help me either.

I am new, and am attempting to use Github pages, but cannot get my page to work. I created this in codepen, and it looked fine and functional there. I assume the issue is in how I am linking my CSS and JS to the HTML.

I tried changing my CSS and JS links several times to no avail. I have no idea what I am doing wrong. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang= "en">
  <head>
    <meta charset= "UTF-8">
    <meta name= "viewport" content="width=device-width, initial"
    <title>Digital Clock:</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/master/style.css">
  </head>

  <body style="background-color:#f28500;">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Press+Start+2P&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <div class="clock">
      <h2><strong>XENA's sundial says:</strong></h1>
      <span class="clock-time"></span> 
      <span class="clock-ampm"></span> 
    </div>
    <script src="/master/digitalClock.js"></script>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the [link](https://github.com/jodyzupancic/vanillaJS) to my actual repo.

******************************************************////
******************************************************////\

UPDATE: I deleted all the above code and link. Please see my answer below for an explanation as to what happened as I somewhat solved the issue.

Comment: Almost certainly because the URL is wrong. Look at the URL of the HTML document. Your code looks like it is written to expect it to be `/` but it is more likely to be `/repository-name/`

Comment: Re edit: Yeah, you're linking to 
 https://jodyzupancic.github.io/master/style.css but the file is at https://jodyzupancic.github.io/vanillaJS/style.css

Answer (score 0):

Urls starting with `/` mean start at the root folder, so you need to change it to be `/YOURPROJECTNAMEHERE/restofurl` where YOURPROJECTNAMEHERE is your project name and restofurl is the rest of the url

Comment: Thank you for your response. As per this solution, I changed my link to: "/vanillaJS/blob/master/style.css",  where /PROJECTNAME/  I took to mean my repo name, and the rest of the link I took from the URL created when I opened the CSS document link. This solution did not work.

Answer (score 0):

should  be test your project  on server  by tools  like [live server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer)
this package related to vscode ide

#### after install live server

[image]

##### then after run  head over to browser in here test address as manual

[image]

#### explain address

example : where address file `talk.ppt`

- `./work/project/talk.ppt`

[image]

#### and final step deploy in github

[image]

Comment: This is for deployment on GitHub Pages, a local server is not related

Comment: @Samathingamajig It is doubtful about  that correctly addressed  in the local environment

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I am unsure as to how this fixes my issue. I already have my page deployed on GH pages. I did download live server regardless, but I am unsure as to why I needed it to check the dev tools. I still do not understand why my path to the css file is not working.

Comment: @fatbandoneonman  with live server check it your webpage is correctly loaded in your pc(local) if correctly loaded ,
 then check it   deploying state . do  step by step.
usually static webpage  like GitHub page's own addressing is straightforward

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out. For some reason, with the code being from codepen, you must export the code to use it, not just copy/paste it (as I had done). I am still unsure as to why I could not get it to work before, however, I deleted everything, and started with a fresh repo and freshly exported code straight from codepen. I did not alter any code. It worked. Previously I copy/pasted it. Further, I uploaded the files from the "src" folder from codepen. I hope this helps somebody in the future.